# ASP.Net MVC Where do you convert from Entities to ViewModels?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, architecture

Title pretty much explains it all, its the last thing I'm trying to work into our project. We are structured with a Service Library which contains a function like so.

```
        /// <summary>
        /// Returns a single category based on the specified ID.
        /// </summary>
        public Category GetCategory(int CategoryID)
        {
            var RetVal = _session.Single<Category>(x => x.ID == CategoryID);
            return RetVal;
        }
```

Now Category is a Entity (We are using Entity Framework) we need to convert that to a CategoryViewModel.

Now, how would people structure this? Would you make sure the service function returned a CategoryViewModel? Have the controller pull the data from the service then call another function to covnert to a view model?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's an excerpt from a [blog post](http://www.bratched.com/en/home/aspnet-mvc/62-how-we-do-aspnet-mvc.html) I wrote:

```
[AutoMap(typeof(IEnumerable<User>), typeof(IEnumerable<UserViewModel>))]
public ActionResult Index()
{
    // return all users
    IEnumerable<User> users = Repository.GetUsers();
    return View(users);
}
```

In this case the corresponding view is strongly typed to `IEnumerable<UserViewModel>`. It uses [AutoMapper](http://automapper.codeplex.com/) to define conversion rules between entities and view models. As for the `[AutoMap]` attribute, it's a custom action filter which inspects the model passed to the view and applies the proper conversion so that the view has only the view model.

Comment: Very elegant solution +1 for that! I'm wary of AutoMapper because of the reflection useage. If the site was recieving 3 request per second is AutoMapper somthing to be concerned about?

Comment: Jimmy Bogard made some great optimizations which improved the performance. He wrote a blog post: http://www.lostechies.com/blogs/jimmy_bogard/archive/2009/08/04/analyzing-automapper-performance.aspx (currently there's a problem opening his blog, so you may also try the cached version: http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:y1UTqDky3wcJ:www.lostechies.com/blogs/jimmy_bogard/archive/2009/08/04/analyzing-automapper-performance.aspx+automapper+reflection+performance&cd=1&hl=en&ct=clnk) Personally I use AutoMapper a lot in production and never had any performance issues with it.

Comment: Thanks :) - In your example where do "IModelMapperController" and "controller.ModelMapper" come from?

Comment: `IModelMapperController` is an interface implemented by my BaseController (not shown in the blog article, I invite you to look at the source code: http://github.com/darind/samplemvc)